# Prove the subset of R is a topology on R

Tags: general-topology

I've got to prove a few subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ form topologies on $\mathbb{R}$, but I haven't got any examples of questions similar to what I am being asked.

$T_1 = ${$\mathbb{R},\emptyset, (a,b)$ where $a$,$b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$ }

The work we have been doing involve questions similar to;
*Let $X = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ and
$\tau_2 = \{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{c,d\},\{a,c,e\},\{b,c,d\}\}$.*

Obviously the first axiom is satisfied as the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ exist in $T_1$ but I am not really sure how to show the second and third axioms are true.

(ii) the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in τ belongs to τ, and
(iii) the intersection of any two sets in τ belongs to τ.

Thanks

Comment: There's only 3 open sets.  What can their unions and intersections possibly be?

Comment: is (a,b) not an interval though rather than the set {a,b}

Comment: This seems to be a confusion in the statement of the question more than anything else.  From the phrasing, I think the question is saying there only one $(a,b)$, but you need to prove that the three-element set is a topology no matter what $a$ and $b$ are.  If the question was saying all open intervals are in $T_1$, then it would not be a topology.

Comment: what the question says is; Which of the following collections of subsets of R form a topology on R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question about $T_2=\{\mathbb{R},\emptyset, (-a,a) \text{ where } a,b \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } a>0 \}$. This is a topology:

The empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ are in $T_2$.

If $(-a_i, a_i)$, $i \in I$, are sets in $T_2$, then their union is

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} {(-a_i, a_i)} = (-a, a), \text{ where } a = \sup_{i\in I}{a_i}.$$

This can be seen by doing an easy inclusion proof in both directions. (In the direction $\supseteq$, when you pick a point $p \in (-a, a)$, it satisfies $-a < p < a$ and by using the definition of supremum you can find a interval $(-a_j, a_j)$ that contains $p$.

So the union is in $T_2$.

The intersection of two sets is easier: when you have two sets of $T_2$, one is always contained in the other, so the intersection is the smaller one, and hence in $T_2$.

EDIT: Proof for $\bigcup_{i\in I} {(-a_i, a_i)} = (-a, a), \text{ where } a = \sup_{i\in I}{a_i}:$

If $x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} {(-a_i, a_i)}$ then $x \in (-a_i, a_i)$ for some $i \in I$. Hence $|x| < a_i \leq sup_{i\in I} a_i = a$ and $x\in (-a, a)$.

On the other hand if $x\in (-a, a)$ we have $|x| < a$. So $a-|x| > 0$ and by definition of supremum there exists an $i$ s.t. $a-a_i < a - |x|$, that is $|x|<a_i$. So

$$x \in (-a_i, a_i) \subset \bigcup_{i\in I} {(-a_i, a_i)}.$$

Comment: how would i start the inclusion proof, i know you said it's easy but i'm not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry I just realised you probably meant that there is only one $(a,b)$ in $T_1$.

Then the union-axiom holds. There are four unions to check The unions with just one element (and with zero elements, i.e $\emptyset$) are trivial. So:

$$(a,b) \cup \mathbb R = \mathbb R \in T_1$$
$$(a,b) \cup \emptyset = (a,b) \in T_1$$
$$\mathbb R \cup \emptyset = \mathbb R \in T_1$$
$$(a,b) \cup \mathbb R \cup \emptyset = \mathbb R \in T_1$$

Likewise for the intersection, only three to check:

$$(a,b) \cap \mathbb R = (a,b) \in T_1$$
$$(a,b) \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \in T_1$$
$$\mathbb R \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \in T_1$$

Comment: Actually, I too would have interpreted the OP's statement as $\{ \mathbb{R}, \{\}, \text{all open intervals}\}$. The "where $a,b$..." should really be written outside of the set-builder.

Comment: I did the above but then didn't think it is correct because I considered (a,b) as the set {a.b} but isn't (a,b) the interval which brings me to the problem of not knowing how to answer the Q.

Comment: Also, @leftroundabout, the "where a,b.." is present in the question I have been given as inside the {}

Comment: Yes, $(a,b)$ is an open interval. What you did is correct. You just check the cases. ( The set $(a,b)$ is just one set. )

Comment: so the above answer is correct?
I have  further questions; T2={ℝ,∅,(-a,a) where a,b∈ℝ and a>0 }is this also a topology then?

Comment: I am confused because for example, (1,2) is in T and (3,4) is in T, but surely (1,2)n(3,4)isn't?

Comment: A third question I have is T3={ℝ,∅,[-a,a] where a,b∈ℝ and a>0 } which makes me think I am doing something wrong

Comment: So do you actually mean that $T$ contains $\mathbb R$, $\emptyset$ and ALL open intervals? Then $T$ isn't a topology, as your counter example shows ($ (1,2)\cup(3,4) \notin T$).

Comment: Was the question formulated as ARE these topologies? Or was it to prove that these are topologies?

Comment: Which of the following collections of subsets of R form a topology on R?

Comment: OK, then I guess $T_1$ is supposed to be the set containing each open interval. As noted this isn't a topology. $T_2$ on the other hand is, since the intervals are contained in one another.

Comment: is there any relevance to the a<b, a>0 and a<0 in the respective questions?

Comment: @ploosu2 How would I prove that T2={ℝ,∅,(-a,a) where a,b∈ℝ and a>0 } IS a topology?

Comment: The relevance of $a<b$ and $a>0$ is that the intervals are defined so that the start point is smaller and end point bigger.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!